# MySQL query to return rows which are not listed in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables in MySQL DB PHPMyAdmin:

`Table-1: T1`

[image]

`Table-2: T2`

[image]

I need to write a mysql query which will return all IMEIs from `T1` which are not listed in `T2`.

For example, in this case query should return `123456781235176`.

Thanks.

Comment: I think that i have posted the same answer as that accepted, before anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this  `select IMEI from T1 where IMEI not in (select IMEI from T2);`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.* FRO table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.IMEI = t2.IMEI
WHERE t2.IMEI IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query

```
Select EMEI from t1 where EMEI not in (select EMEI from t2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select IMEI from T1 where IMEI not in 
(
    select a.IMEI from T1 as a inner join T2 as b on a.IMEI = b.IMEI
) as exp
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IMEI FROM T1 WHERE IMEI NOT IN(SELECT IMEI FROM T2);
```